# Работа с БД только через процедуры и функции

Tags: mysql

Задача следующая - нужно разрешить работать с базой только через сохраненные процедуры.

Возможно ли ограничить доступ в MySQL к простым операциям: SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE и пр. таким образом, чтобы в сохраненных процедурах/функциях эти операции работали?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При создании процедуры можно указать ее создателя (по умолчанию, это CURRENT_USER) и права, с которыми она выполняется. Права могут быть DEFINER (выполнять с правами создателя) и INVOKER (выполнять с правами вызвавшего пользователя). Таким образом, процедура

```
CREATE DEFINER = 'root'@'localhost' PROCEDURE sp_name
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN
  ..........
END
```

может выполнить что угодно, вне зависимости от того, какие права у вызвавшего пользователя